# How can I count number of occurrence in one column and add the next respective column in MYSQL, PHP and present to datatable

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, datatable

I get this error when correcting the below php,
although yesterday I alter my table few things.

DataTables warning: table id=categories - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error,

```
**DB**
**id    siteid      sitenm        cat         comm**
   1    TS002AAA    Kimara        DSM          47
   2    TS899DDDD   Igawilo       Mbeya        11
  10    TS0004AAA   Malamba       Mbezi        21
   3    TS003AAA    Mapana TTCL   Tanga         3
   9    TS0003AAA   Mivinjeni     Tanga         1
```

**OUTPUT SHOULD LOOK LIKE**

```
**No    cat         total_site    total_comments**
   1    DSM           2                 68
   2    Mbeya         1                 11
   3    Tanga         2                 39
```

**PHP**

When I run php script itself I found this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\altech\scripts\fetchcat.php:29 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\altech\scripts\fetchcat.php on line 29

```
    <?php
    //fetch.php
    include('config.php');
     
    $columns = array('sitenm', 'cat', 'comm');
    
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT cat, COUNT(sitenm) AS total_sites, SUM(comm) AS total_comm FROM systemsites GROUP BY cat");
    
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
       /* echo $row{'cat'}." ";
        echo $row{'total_sites'}." ";
        echo $row{'total_comm'}." "."</br>";*/
    }
    
    if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
    {
     $query .= 'WHERE sitenm LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
     OR sitenm LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
     ';
    }
    
    if(isset($_POST["order"]))
    {
     $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$columns[$_POST['order']['0']['column']].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' 
     ';
    }
    else
    {
    $query .= 'ORDER BY siteid DESC ';
    }
    
    $query1 = '';
    
    if($_POST["length"] != -1)
    {
     $query1 = 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
    }
    
    $number_filter_row = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query . $query1);
    
    $data = array();
    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
     $sub_array = array();
     $sub_array[] = '<div data-id="'.$row["id"].'" data-column="sitenm">' . $row["cat"] . '</div>';
     $sub_array[] = '<div data-id="'.$row["id"].'" data-column="cat">' . $row["total_sites"] . '</div>';    
     $sub_array[] = '<div data-id="'.$row["id"].'" data-column="comm">' . 
        $row["comm"] . '</div>';
         $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger 
        btn-xs delete" id="'.$row["id"].'">Delete</button>';
         $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="preview" class="btn btn-success 
        btn-xs preview" id="'.$row["id"].'">Liew Preview</button>';
         $data[] = $sub_array;
        }
    
        function get_all_data($connect)
        {
         $query = "SELECT * FROM systemsites";
         $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
         return mysqli_num_rows($result);
        }
   
        $output = array(
         "draw"    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
         "recordsTotal"  =>  get_all_data($connect),
         "recordsFiltered" => $number_filter_row,
         "data"    => $data
         );
    
         echo json_encode($output);
         ?>
```

**JS**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //fetch cat data    
      fetch_data();
      function fetch_data()
      {
       var dataTable = $('#categories').DataTable({
        "processing" : true,
        "serverSide" : true,
        "order" : [],
        "ajax" : {
         url:"../scripts/fetchcat.php",
         type:"POST"
        },
           "columns": [
      { "data": "sitenm" },
      { "data": "total_sites" },
      { "data": "total_comm" },
    ]
       });
      }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: first please add sample table directly and ask question properly, , btw to isplay in datatable, you need to write sql that gives output like this, and it seems it only requires one join to your places table,

Comment: I posted sample tables

Answer (score 0):

you can use group by on region and count for places and sum for comments

tested on pgsql

```
select region, count(Places) total_places, sum (Comments) as total_comments
from table
group by region
```

and in your datatable code

```
//    datatables
"ajax" ...
"columns": [
{
    "data": "cat" ,
    "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
        return '<div data-id="'.data.sitenm.'" data-column="sitenm">' . data.cat .'</div>';     
    },
{
    "data": "total_places" ,
    "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
        return '<div data-id="'.data.id.'" data-column="cat">' . data.total_sites . '</div>';    
    },
{
    "data": "comm" ,
    "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
        return ''<div data-id="'.data.id.'" data-column="comm">' . data.comm . '</div>';    
    }
,{
    "data": null,
    "render": function ( data, type, row ) {

        var btn = '<button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" id="'.data.id.'">Delete</button>';
        btn +=  '<button type="button" name="preview" class="btn btn-success btn-xs preview" id="'.data.id.'">Liew Preview</button>';

    return  btn;    
    }
}

]
```

or just do it simply

```
[
        { "data": "cat"}
        { "data": "total_sites"     },
        { "data": "comm" }  ,
        {
            data: null,
            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {

                var btn = '<button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" id="'.data.id.'">Delete</button>';
                btn +=  '<button type="button" name="preview" class="btn btn-success btn-xs preview" id="'.data.id.'">Liew Preview</button>';

            return  btn;    
            }
        }
    ]
```

return result array and render html in columnsdef

```
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$output = array(
 "draw"    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
 "recordsTotal"  =>  get_all_data($connect),
 "recordsFiltered" => $number_filter_row,
 "data"    => $data
 );

 echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Hello Sir Yesterday I failed some were please check above code

Comment: ok i know what is the problem, the array you return does not have keys, you need to return key value pair for rows,  and if you want html, you can use render function in js